# What's the correct use of dynamic Facebook UTMs for Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, advertising, ppc, utm-parameters, facebook-ads-manager

This question has two parts: best practice, and issues with reporting.

---

### Best practice:

Right now, the UTMs that we've set up for our Facebook & Instagram advertising campaigns are dynamically generated.

**Option A**

We're currently using the following set up in the Facebook Ads Manager:

```
?utm_source={{site_source_name}}
&utm_medium={{placement}}
&utm_campaign={{campaign.name}}_{{adset.name}}
&utm_content={{ad.name}}
```

**Option B**

We've also considered splitting out the adset name into a separate URL parameter:

```
?utm_source={{site_source_name}}
&utm_medium={{placement}}
&utm_campaign={{campaign.name}}
&utm_term={{adset.name}}
&utm_content={{ad.name}}
```

However, I'm not sure if the `content` and `term` parameters are the best fit for this?

***Question 1: Which one of the above is best practice?***

---

### Issues with reporting:

With either setup, this means that in the **Acquision > All Traffic > Channels** report in Google Analytics, everything gets lumped under **(Other)**:

[image]

Only therein you'll have `fb` and `ig` — separated away from other paid channels. That doesn't seem right. [Facebook's help page on this](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1016122818401732) didn't provide complete clarity on the matter.

***Question 2: Is this set up right? Or is there a better way of using Facebook's dynamic parameters to set up UTMs according to [Google's guidelines](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/)?***

```
ad_id={{ad.id}}
adset_id={{adset.id}}
campaign_id={{campaign.id}}
ad_name={{ad.name}}
adset_name={{adset.name}}
campaign_name={{campaign.name}}
placement={{placement}}
site_source_name={{site_source_name}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

utm_term would usually relate to *paid search* advertising that is targeting searches for particular keywords such as with Google (or Bing) Searches.

If they are ad placements/display, if you use utm_medium=display, it will bucket it into the default Display channel in GA.

You can find a list of the GA default channel definitions on the following page:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3297892

You can also create your own channels, or edit existing channels too, however bare in mind, the changes are not retroactive.

If it were me, I would probably use something along the lines of the following:
?utm_source={{site_source_name}}
&utm_medium=display
&utm_campaign={{campaign.id}}
&utm_content={{adset.name}}_{{ad.name}}
&placement={{placement}}
- while placement is not a utm parameter, it still offers useful information even if appended to a url

Comment: Thanks! Yep, for sure. I agree with you about utm_term. Anything 'wrong' with using it that way? Or just not useful? I guess all Facebook advertising is display, no? (Video too, but that's technically display?)

Comment: FB now also has search ads https://www.facebook.com/business/news/reach-people-who-are-actively-shopping-with-ads-in-facebook-search-results
What I would do is try to find some way to distinguish with display ads whether they are image, video or text display ads